# ORA-01017 : invalid username/password ; logon denied

Tags: forms, oracle11g

I'm a beginner in the oracle forms 11g into windows 7 and I use the google chrome as a browser. But whenever I compile and run my forms (without error) I had this error in the browser: `ORA-01017 : invalid username/password ; logon denied`

I had also this warning before the logon message error :

```
the connection to this website is untrusted and the link of the site
```

Comment: You're using an invalid username or password, maybe?

Comment: Hi,no i log well on forms otherwise i can't run well my form

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 11g a new parameter called `SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON` which is defaults to TRUE for case sensitive passwords. My SCOTT password was "tiger" is small case and Forms 10g was taking it as "TIGER" on runtime.

Solution 1:
- Connect as sys and change the parameter to false.

```
alter system set SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE;
```

Solution 2:
- Connect as DBA and change the password of SCOTT to LETTER case.

```
alter user scott identified by TIGER;
```